# How can I avoid separating my class into headers and source files without compiler errors?

Tags: c++

I'm a hobby programmer working on small projects. I find that separating class definition from declaration only makes it harder to work with my classes. Compiler and linker errors related to multiple definitions or classes depending on each other's member functions are forcing me to do it though. Is there any way to avoid the errors while not separating class definition from declaration? Failing that, is there a way to keep the class in one file? I keep reading that I should never include a source file.

Comment: Include guards and forward declarations usually do the job, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Include_Guard_Macro

Comment: The errors I'm talking about cannot be prevented with include guards. Besides, I know how to fix the errors. I just want to avoid doing so by separating class definition from declaration because I prefer to not split up my code.

Comment: C++ is a language that requires declarations! you can avoid declarations until you have a class A that depends on something in class B while class B depends on something in class A.

Comment: What kind of errors / problems are you talking about then? Include guards prevent linker errors that are due to multiple definitions of the same thing, forward declarations solve problems with circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, but it may increase considerably your compilation times if you have complex classes. It is as simple as to keep every thing "inside" the class:

```
#ifndef __ACLASS_H__
#define __ACLASS_H__

class A {
public:
  A() : i(0) {}

  int getI() { return i; }
  void setI(int _i) { i = _i; }

protected:
  int i;
};
#endif
```

The `#ifndef` directive is necessary to avoid multiple declarations.

Using forward declaration when possible (pointers to classes, for example) also reduces complexity in the dependency tree of classes.

Comment: what you are doing is not only keeping them in header files but also declaring them implicitly inline!

Comment: Well, actually for those so-simple get/set is the most convenient ;)

Comment: yes thats true. but if the OP starts dragging all code into   inline functions he might get more than he was expecting. furthermore he will become forwarding problems if he does so for all his classes. while this advice is correct I believe it is dangerous if you don't explain the consequences of doing so as well.

Comment: On current compiles `inline` is less than a hint - actually, VC++ explicitly says it ignores it completely -, so I wouldn't worry about this specific fact...

Comment: Right. Actually, I usually prefer to let only simple and straightforward definitions in header files, while moving more complex code into several .cpp files, also reducing compilation times, but it is actually the opposite @A.B. asked.